# To prevent systemd initialization at/after Debian OS startup

Tags: debian, systemd, startup

How do we prevent systemd initialization at/after OS (Debian MX linux) startup ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Disabling systemd will render your system unusable as you won't even get a login prompt. Also, your question is kinda ... weird: startup **is** systemd initialization.

Comment: If you are looking for a systemd-free debian derivative, [devuan](https://www.devuan.org/) might be the closest option.

Comment: MX Linux is special because it allows to choose the initialization method: SysV or `systemd`.

Comment: @Fiximan Debian 10 supports sysvinit instead of systemd too.

Comment: @StephenKitt "Since jessie, only systemd is fully supported; sysvinit is mostly supported, but Debian packages are not required to provide sysvinit start scripts." [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Init) - one might face troubles.

Comment: @Fiximan that wiki change was made by a Debian user, not a Debian developer, and is somewhat ahead of policy; the version of policy which was current when Debian 10 was released still required init scripts. Starting with Debian 11, administrators will probably see a drop in support; but Debian 10 is still usable with sysvinit (at least as long as GNOME is not required). I have a number of Debian 10 systems running without systemd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/systemd/), MX Linux boots with SysV initialization by default. You need to enter an advanced boot option to use `systemd`. Therefore, one solution is to boot normally.

However, you may have disabled SysV initialization by installing `systemd-sysv`. In this case, simply delete `systemd-sysv` to re-enable it.